# DataFrame.describe method ignores some of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to "describe" function in Pandas on my dataframe but it is only showing one column instead of the four I have imported in my CSV file. Note that I am using Jupyter to do this.

Below are the outputs that show what the DataFrame looks like as well as the results of `describe`.  Does anyone know why I am not getting back all  columns when using describe?  Does it have something to do with my file which is a simple CSV file?

```
hist.head()

   Year  Month     Overall      Mobile
0  2016   July  76,762,352  65,908,711
1  2016   June  76,523,713  65,465,770
2  2016    May  77,057,451  65,297,809
3  2016  April  76,722,596  64,739,144
4  2016  March  78,258,917  66,287,421
```

---

```
hist.describe()    
              Year
count    67.000000
mean   2013.313433
std       1.634931
min    2011.000000
25%    2012.000000
50%    2014.000000
75%    2015.000000
max    2016.000000
```

Answer (score 4):

When the DataFrame contains at least one numerical column, df.describe() only describes the numerical column(s). It means that your other columns are not treated as numbers. You can confirm that by typing `df.dtypes` (it will return object for the other columns).

The problem in your DataFrame is the thousands separator. You can pass `pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', thousands=',')` to read it correctly. `sep` part is just a guess based on the thousands separator. You might need to change it based on your file.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it doesn't seem to work either.  I'd like to post another screen shot here but it doesn't look like it will let me.         hist.head() gives me 2016,July," 76,762,352 "," 65,908,171 "," 10,9... for one row which is not how it should look.

Comment: Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39352696/edit) your post to include a few lines of your CSV file?

Comment: Isn't that what head() is doing though?

Comment: That's the converted version. I was asking for the original file's rows so that I can try read_csv on it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response. Hope it helps someone.

In addition to ayhan reply,

If you think your column has numerical values, change the type to float:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].astype(float)
```